# Google Play Store Fails to upload app icon with "blocked by CORS policy" error

Tags: android, google-play

I'm in the process of submitting our app to the Google Play Store. When I go to upload the App Icon into the Store Listing section it continuously fails with "Couldn't upload. Try again.". Checking the network logs it's failing with the following:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://playconsoleapps-pa.clients6.google.com/upload/v1/developers/11111111111/apps/1111111111/images/1?alt=protojson' from origin 'https://play.google.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Just wondering if anyone has seen this and has any fix? Have tried incog as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gave it the weekend and resubmitted the image and it is now working. Must have been a blip in the google developer universe.

Comment: it's happening again, oh shit: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://playconsoleapps-pa.clients6.google.com/upload/v1/developers/6795301…4Vx4Dgvu_T_1QdmIjs0YNRJ1St6hk56Ykx9EQpRJd2a3tgjQ&upload_protocol=resumable' from origin 'https://play.google.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: @Elizandro-SparcBR with me too

Comment: @YuliiaAshomok my colleague tried on his computer and it worked.. strange